# Prove that every solution to $z''+e^{z^2}=1$ is periodic.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a problem from a homework assignment that is causing me some trouble.

The technique provided in the section is as follows.

- Set $x=z,y=z'$ and convert the second order ODE to a linear system. In this case, we have $$(x,y)'=(y,1-e^{x^2})$$
- Find the orbits of the linear system by solving $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-e^{x^2}}{y}$. The orbits turn out to be level sets of $(x,y)\rightarrow \frac{y^2}{2}+\int_0^x e^{t^2}\mathrm{d}t-x$

If an aforementioned orbit forms a  *closed curve* that *doesn't contain an equilibrium point* (the only equilibrium point of this system is the origin, FYI) then any solution to this system passing through a point on said orbit is periodic.

Unfortunately, these level sets are *not* closed. Is there any other way to attack this problem? I assumed the problem set required the student to solve the problem using this theory since this theory was presented and proved in the corresponding section.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the value of the initial condition matters in this question. That is, there is a range of values $I \subsetneq \mathbb R$ such that if the initial condition $z(0) \in I$ then periodicity holds, and if $z(0) \notin I$ then periodicity doesn't hold.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer the problem is stated in the title, word for word, from the textbook.

Comment: I understand. The problem is, I looked at a rough plot of the solution for different initial values and some of the pictures do not look like those of periodic functions. However, the method suggested by you is not the only method that is used to show periodicity. One way is to show that for some $P$, $y(x) = z(P+x)$ is also a solution, and then use uniqueness. Another is to consider $y(x) = z(P+x)-z(x)$, find the differential equation satisfied by this difference and show that $y \equiv 0$ works for some $P$. These are only methods, I'll have to see if they work.

Comment: The task is indeed defective. The stationary point is singular, that is, it does not have a regular Jacobian. This would be different if the right side had a larger value. Or if the equation had an additional factor, $z''+z(e^{z^2}-1)=0$. Also removing the square would help, $z''+e^z-1=0$. Even increasing the power would make the claim true, $z''+e^{z^3}=1$.